# Проскролить страницу для парсинга объектов на Python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Например, есть такая страница: https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/smesiteli/dlya-vanny-s-dushem/?digiSearch=true&term=santek&params=%7Csort%3DDEFAULT

На ней находятся элементы, ссылки на которые надо собрать. Но они подгружаются при скроле страницы (посмотрел, происходит такой запрос типа: https://sort.diginetica.net/search?st=santek&apiKey=18O0VD92Y8&strategy=vectors_strict,zero_queries_predictor&fullData=true&withCorrection=true&withFacets=true&treeFacets=true&regionId=global&useCategoryPrediction=false&size=20&offset=40&showUnavailable=true&unavailableMultiplier=0.2&preview=false&withSku=false&sort=DEFAULT и меняется offset на 20 каждый раз).

Пробовал прокрутить страницу при помощи Selenium, но страница не прокручивается ( так же и в ручном режиме, только при наведении на основную часть страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будьте добры подсказать метод как можно собрать все элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import requests


res = requests.get('https://sort.diginetica.net/search?st=santek&apiKey=18O0VD92Y8&'
                   'strategy=vectors_strict,zero_queries_predictor&fullData=true&'
                   'withCorrection=true&withFacets=true&treeFacets=true&regionId=global&'
                   'useCategoryPrediction=false&size=40&offset=0&showUnavailable=true&'
                   'unavailableMultiplier=0.2&preview=false&withSku=false&sort=DEFAULT')
for i, x in enumerate(res.json()['products'], 1):
    name = x['name']
    link = f"https://stl-nn.com{x['link_url']}"
    print(i, name)
    print(link)

1 Умывальник Балтика 60, Santek
https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/umyvalniki/umyvalnik-baltika-60-santek/
2 Унитаз-компакт SANTEK Лига, 1.WH30.2.141, 2 режима
https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/unitazy-i-komplektuyuschie/unitazy/unitaz-kompakt-liga-standart-2-rej-dyuro-metal-krepej/
......
39 Унитаз-компакт Santek Римини 1.WH50.1.523 косой выпуск
https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/unitazy-i-komplektuyuschie/unitazy/unitaz-kompakt-rimini-ekonom-2-rezh-poliprop/
40 Унитаз-компакт Santek Нео 1.WH30.2.418 безободковый
https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/unitazy-i-komplektuyuschie/unitazy/unitaz-kompakt-bezobodkovyy-neo-rimless-standart-2-rezh.-dyuro-metal-krepezh-softclose-tonkoe/
```

Проскролить страницу используем `offset=0` в адресе сайта например `offset=40` и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли! Пытался сделать похожее, но почему-то выдавал не полный json-список

Comment: Количество элементов на странице задаётся параметром size в адресе запроса

Answer (score 1):

Если цель собрать, то попробуйте с помощью requests-html

Пример:

```
    from requests_html import HTMLSession

    session = HTMLSession()
    url = 'https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/smesiteli/dlya-vanny-s-dushem/?digiSearch=true&term=santek&params=%7Csort%3DDEFAULT'

    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render()
    text = r.html.find('a')
    print(text)

    >>> ... <Element 'a' href='https://stl-nn.com/santehnika/smesiteli/vstraivaemyy-termostat-dlya-vannoy-ili-dusha-grohtherm-1000-34160000-grohe/' class=('product__title',) title='Встраиваемый термостат для ванной или душа Grohtherm 1000, 34160000, GROHE'>, <Element 'a' class=('button', 'button_bookmark', 'cm-submit', 'text-button') data-ca-dispatch='dispatch[wishlist.add..2923]' rel=('nofollow',)> ...
```

Пробовал BS4, Selenium - не берет.